# Python скрипт, генерирующий изображение png Pyplot Matplotlib - запуск из PHP

Tags: php, python, изображения, localhost, matplotlib

Приветствую!
Есть скрипт python в файле test.py:

```
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    '''
    Основной код: получаем значения в переменную result и данные для plt
    '''

    print result
    #plt.show() #Показать результат - Matplotlib Pyplot-изображение - отключен
    plt.savefig('path_to_file/test.png') #Сохранить результат - Matplotlib Pyplot - изображение в файл
```

path_to_file - руть к папке в директории на серевере localhost.
При запуске данного скрипта в **bash (через терминал, командную строку)** в терминале печатается значение переменной result, в path_to_file появляется test.png. Все  создается, все выводится - **Ок**.

Теперь пробуем запустить тестирование скрипта на PHP-сервере (Apache2):
Данный файл запускается из php-скрипта test.php на сервере c:

```
    <?php
    $pytask = 'python test.py';
    echo "<br>" .$pytask,"<br>";  // Displaying command - Ok
    $command = escapeshellcmd($pytask);//Для shell-команды в cmd - экранирование
    $output = shell_exec($command);//Выполнение shell-команды
    echo "<p>",$output,"</p>";
    echo '<p><img src="/path_to_file/test.png" alt="Результат расчета"/></p>';// Или img src="path_to_file/test.png"
    ?>
```

При открытии на страничке **localhost/test.php** значение переменной result отображается - **Ок**, 
НО в path_to_file **НЕ** создается test.png - **Fail**.

Предполагаю, что дело в потоках: поток данных создаваемого файла png идет в html-код, генерируемый php-скриптом. А надо чтобы он шел в файловую систему (надеюсь, что объяснение понятное). Если это так, подскажите, как направить поток в нужное русло?

Или дело не в этом? Тогда проще вопрос: ***как создать файл png c помощью python-скрипта, вызывая его из php?*** Если можно, с простым примером. (Лучше используя pyplot, matplotlib).

*Прим. В python-скрипт затем будут передаваться передаются параметры из php (типа*

```
    $pytask = 'python test.py ' .$param_from_php;
```

*). Поэтому нужно запускать python-скрипт именно из php.*

Answer (score 1):

Открой консоль сервера и экспериментируй там.

Первым наперво - вызывай python правильно (местоположение бинарника может быть другим)

```
/usr/bin/python test.py
```

Второе, путь к файлу с картинкой - укажи полный (абсолютный)

```
plt.savefig('/var/www/site.ru/httpdocs/images/test.png')
```

Перенаправь STD_ERR в STD_OUT

```
2>&1
```

Итоговую команду, которая будет работать из консоли, помести в php

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/python test.py 2>&1")
```

**EDIT:**

Чтобы не решать проблему через chmod можно сделать bash скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/python test.py
```

настроить его

```
chmod +x /var/www/site.ru/bash_folder/bash.sh
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/site.ru/bash_folder/bash.sh
```

и запускать его через права определенного пользователя используя sudo

```
sudo -u www-data /var/www/site.ru/bash_folder/bash.sh 2>&1
```

В файл /etc/sudoers надо добавить пользователя www-data и дать ему право на выполнение конкретного этого скрипта, скажем так:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/site.ru/bash_folder/bash.sh
```

www-data это обычно пользователь под которым запускается apache или nginx, и ему мы даём право на запуск этого скрипта без пароля

Comment: Python отрабатывет код правильно. Он не может писать в директорию "path_to_file" = "/var/www/site.ru/httpdocs/images/". Мне пришлось просто сделать chmod на нее. Но это не лучшее решение.

Comment: У вас должна быть своя директория, в которой находится сайт. Указанная мной - всего лишь пример. Я сейчас подредактирую ответ касательно прав доступа

Comment: Ну, конечно) Естественно у меня своя директория (о ней и речь), иначе как бы можно было на несуществующую/"левую" директорию поставить chmod.

Comment: Дополнение (на заметку): чтобы посмотреть результат скрипта в консоли без затрагивания потоков *stderr/out*, можно воспользоваться командой *sudo* *-u* *www-data* *php* *index.php* непосредственно из терминала. Она удобно позволяет схватывать ошибки и отлаживать "на лету", без *shell_exec("... 2>&1")* нагромождения в php-коде страницы.

Comment: Привыкай указывать полный путь бинарника, который запускаешь - к примеру /usr/bin/php. Встречаются системы на которых настроенны скажем несколько версий php, соответственно это поможет вызывать нужную тебе.